# How to convert a folder full of .csv files into .xlsx files with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xlsx

Situation: I have a folder full of .csv files (over 100) that I want to convert into individual .xlsx files using a `for` loop. I tried the following code, and encountered some problems/questions

```
import pandas as pd
import os

for file in os.listdir("M:\example_path\csv"):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        # print(file)
        read_file = pd.read_csv(file)
        read_file.to_excel("M:\example_path\csv", index=None, header=True)
```

Problem 1: I get the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` from `read_file`, but `print(file)` can list all the .csv files in that folder.

Problem 2: If I want to give each converted .xlsx file the same name as the .csv file (i.e. convert `a.csv` into `a.xlsx`, `b.csv` into `b.xlsx` etc.), how should I achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You forgot to join paths. `file_path = os.path.join("M:\example_path\csv", file)`.

Comment: @Mercury do you mean that I should add `file_path = os.path.join("M:\example_path\csv", file)` before `read_file` and change to `pd.read_csv(file_path)` ?

Comment: Yes. Any file that is not in your current working directory needs the full path in order to be loaded.

Comment: @Mercury Okay, thank you for your help. Do you happen to have an idea about the second problem as well?

Comment: For changing the suffix: `filename.split('.')[0] + '.xlsx'`

Comment: @DS_London I think you misunderstood. Converting a single .csv file into .xlsx file would require first `read_file = pd.read_csv("example.csv")` and then `read_file.to_excel("example.xlsx")`. But since I want to use this is a `for` loop, I am not sure how I should go about it.

Comment: I was addressing Problem 2. In your code `file_pathXlsx = file_path.split('.') + '.xlsx'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you could use `glob.glob()` which would then let you just match `.csv` files. `os.path.splitext()` can be used to help with creating a suitable output filename:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from glob import glob

for csv_file in glob(r"M:\example_path\csv\*.csv"):
    print(csv_file)
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    xlsx_file = os.path.splitext(csv_file)[0] + '.xlsx'
    df.to_excel(xlsx_file, index=None, header=True)
```

Also don't forget to add `r` before the file path to stop Python parsing the `\` characters.